# nodejs decode (child processes use)

Tags: windows, node.js, utf-8, decode

I use spawn for JScript (from windows)
My problem with decode text

???? ??? T-SQL Microsoft SQL Server 2012

???? ??? - russian text.

```
var worker,path = require('path'), spawn = require('child_process').spawn, cscript = path.join(process.env.SystemRoot, 'system32', 'cscript.exe')

 function startCscript() {
    worker = spawn( cscript, [ '/nologo', 'testwsh.js' ] );
    worker.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
    worker.stdout.on( 'data', onData );
}

function onData (data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
}
startCscript();
```

How do I get Russian letters? Thanks all )

Comment: is it possible that your cscript is outputing like that ?

Comment: what version of windows are you using ? Is it possible that the whole OS can't display cyrrilic letters ?

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600], Russian.

Comment: If the script is run as: cscript my_cscript.js (cscript.js: WSH.Echo ("everything is OK")), then all is well, I can see the Russian text!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution: use iconv-lite, to get the Russian text in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to set the worker encoding as `ucs2` or `utf16le`.
Change this

```
worker.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
```

to this

```
worker.stdout.setEncoding('ucs2');
```

Tell if it solves the issue.

Comment: result ufcs2 : service.js:107
敢楧㩮海彩潨晴硩䌺灡楴湯䠬瑯楆䥸ⱄ湉瑳污敬佤൮栊瑴㩰⼯潧洮捩潲潳瑦挮浯是汷湩⽫.................

Answer (score 0):

look at [issue 2190](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2190) and [issue 2196](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2196):

> Node.js does always expect UTF-8 output from a child process, but
>   Windows with Russian locale defaults to CP866

you need to execute `chcp 65001` to change current console code page.

Comment: Hm, not work. Console.log is empty :(                                                                 var spawn = require('child_process').spawn, path = require('path'), 
 cscript = path.join(process.env.SystemRoot, 'system32', 'cscript.exe'),

worker = spawn ('chcp 866|' + cscript, ['/nologo', '1.js']);

worker.stdout.on( 'data' , function ( data ) {
 console.log(data.toString());
});